# Convert Spark.sql timestamp to java.time.Instant in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

**Very Simple question** - Need to convert timestamp column in spark dataframe to java.time.Instant format

[image]

Comment: Taking a quick look to the [**Scaladoc** of **Spark**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html) and the [**Javadoc** of `java.sql.Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) I then realize that you probably want to do `val time1 = spar.sql("...").as[java.sql.Timestamp].first().toInstant`

Comment: Thanks @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez. This was really helpful and resolved my issue :)

Answer (score 1):

Here you can convert to `java.time.instant`:

```scala
val time1 = spark
  .sql("...")
  .as[java.sql.Timestamp]
  .first()
  .toInstant
```